# Screen does not appear in list when using sudo

Tags: sudo, sh, gnu-screen

While under `root` user (printed by `whoami`), execution of

```
sh -c "screen -d -m -S testscreen sh -c \"echo asd; echo qwe\""
```

creates a screen with two lines output, which can be reattached via `screen -r testcreen`

But if I'm using

```
sudo -n -u root sh -c "screen -d -m -S testscreen sh -c \"echo asd; echo qwe\""
```

the screen does not appear in list. What's wrong and what should I do instead?

(CentOS 5.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your screen binary location is not in the $PATH being used by sh.  So when you sudo, because you aren't invoking the login shell to setup a new environment, the command won't exist.  You can verify this by checking a couple things.

become root:

```
$ sudo -s
# which screen
/some/path/to/screen
# echo $PATH
```

The easiest way to fix this is to specify the full path to screen in the command you are using:

```
$ sudo -n -u root sh -c "/some/path/to/screen -d -m -S testscreen sh -c \"echo asd; echo qwe\""
```

If that doesn't fix it, it would be helpful to capture if sh is having some other issue starting the screen by doing:

```
$ sudo -n -u root sh -c "set -x ; screen -d -m -S testscreen sh -c \"echo asd; echo qwe\""
```

Answer (score 1):

The screen is added to the root user, use `sudo screen -raAd` to reattach

Comment: Screen list, with or without `sudo`, is equal, so there is no such screen too.

Comment: Don't have a Linux box around atm, can't test it.